# Determine whether the dice is biased based on 10 rolls

Tags: probability

> A casino game has two dice, each with faces
>   numbered $1$ to $6$. One of them is fair but the
>   other is biased such that a $6$ is twice as likely
>   to appear on top as any one of the other faces. 
>   One of the dice is rolled $10$ times, and a
>   $6$ appears on top exactly four times. What is the
>   probability that the die was the biased one?

I get the probability of the biased die as $\frac 2 7$ but from there I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event: "is rolled $10$ times, and a $6$ appears on top four times".

Then $$
P(A|biased) = \binom {10}4 (2/7)^4 (5/7)^6\\
P(A|unbiased) = \binom {10}4 (1/6)^4 (5/6)^6\\
$$

Then write
$$P(biased|A) = 
\frac{P(A, biased)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(A|biased) P(biased)}{P(A|biased) P(biased) +
P(A|unbiased) P(unbiased)}
$$

Comment: Can you please explain why this works and your thinking/plan?

Comment: this is the bayes property.

Comment: do you have a link?

Comment: of course: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem

Comment: I got u +1, but i'm not the OP.

Comment: But the answer says 0.774 008, and with thus calculation you will get 0.854467